# asp.net MVC jquery grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying a hello world project with ASP.net MVC and jquery grid

Followed the steps as per http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Everything seems to be fine when hitting F5 from VS2008. the grid is showing the data from the db

Now, when I set up a virtual directory and pointed to the same project, no data comes up

So I tried modifying the URL property of jquery grid from

```
    //url: '/Home/GetGridData/',
```

to 
url: '<% =Url.Action("GetGridData","~/Home") %>',

Still the data does not show up

Using fiddler, the differences when running in F5 mode and in virtual directory mode, there is the difference in the URL being requested

F5
http://localhost.:1188/Home/GetGridData?nd=1267102892819&_search=false&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Activity&sord=asc

Virtual directory
http://mymachine/dashboard/Home/GetGridData?nd=1267102919267&_search=false&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Sno&sord=asc

Now, how do i fix up this error

Comment: Is your connection string consistent? Is the virtual directory on the same system as your development environment? If not, could the other system have an empty db?

Comment: Is your connection string consistent? Yes its the web.config 



Is the virtual directory on the same system as your development environment? same system

Comment: Are there any javascript errors being reported by the browser? IE8 IE Dev Tools or Firefox+Firebug are excellent resources for that.

Comment: initially there were js errors like 404 for files for jquery 
i fixed them up
after that no 404 except for the one specified in the question

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `Url.Action` should be controllerName, not a virtual path.
Use `"Home"` instead of `"~/Home"`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, yes i tried with HOME instead of the virtual path
that too didnt work

Comment: Did you change the url for javascript/css? I tried the example and it works fine for me, except i hade to change src and href for 
javascript/css files to use "<%=Url.Content("")%>".

Comment: Yes tahts been done too.
due to that i was able to get rid of 404 for jquery files as said earlier

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify URL ROUTING OR ADD NEW ROUTING.
Virtual machine URL is parsing wrongly.